# angular 2 : how to iterate images with *ngFor from firebase storage

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I am attempting iterate images stored in Firebase storage. I successfully uploading images with associated metadata into Firebase. However, I would not be able to fetch images from storage. For a single image, it worked perfectly fine. However, I would not be able to fetch **multiple images** on multiple listings page.

Please check my code and nicely give me your answer.

> The exception error thrown in console --> EXCEPTION: Firebase Storage: Invalid argument in child at index 0: Expected string.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'; 
import {ProgramFirebaseService} from '../../services/programfirebase.service';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

@Component({
selector: 'app-program-listings',
 templateUrl: './program-listings.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./program-listings.component.css']
})
export class ProgramListingsComponent implements OnInit {
listings : any;
image: any;
  constructor(private service: ProgramFirebaseService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    //this.listings =[];
    //this.image =[];
    this.service.getListings().subscribe((listings:any)=>{

      console.log(listings);
      this.listings = listings;
     // get reference from storage
     let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
     let spaceRef = storageRef.child(listings.path);
     // download the url
      storageRef.child(listings.path).getDownloadURL().then((url)=>{
      // url is firebase path which we store as a var imageUrl
      listings.image = url;
      console.log("this is ok");
      });


    });




  }

}






The html potion related to is along with above ts file. 
<div *ngFor="let lst of listings"> <img sytle="width:50%" src=lst.image>
```

Comment: This is just a banal thought, your img tag should be `<img style="width:50%" [src]="lst.image">`. If that is the actual problem...

Comment: I do not believe that is the issue ... I checked it.. But I still have the same console error.